# How can I recover progress that was unable to be saved in Undertale?

Tags: undertale

I'm trying to help my kid who is playing Undertale. She finally defeated Muffet after a year of playing, and then there was a glitch and nowhere for her to save file.

She was in the Hot Lands and Mettaton Box form was fighting her. She defeated Muffet then the game locked up and there was no save file anywhere for her to save the file to.

If she was killed by Mettaton her last save was before Muffet.

How can we recover this progress?

Comment: I do not know the game, but as a general rule, "Everything not saved will be lost" - Quote by Nintendo. Unless the game has an autosave feature, you cannot recover a save that didnt exist or wasnt updated with more recent data.

Comment: Nooooooo! She was so happy when she defeated the character and I told her it was bedtime and she was trying to hurry up and that's when she lost

Comment: Maybe add more details, e.g. Which character and what the general issue is making this that hard. Maybe there's some simple mechanic you're missing and it can be repeated within minutes.

Comment: Certain actions are remembered by Undertale even if you haven't saved your game. This is an intentional game mechanic.

Answer (score 4):

If you really didn't want to start again you could create a new save using this tool: https://crumblingstatue.github.io/FloweysTimeMachine/
You can use this to find the existing save you have and use the tool to edit it to the point that your daughter got to.

Comment: Is this considered a "hack"? She's afraid to try it bc she doesn't want to be kicked off the game.

Comment: Undertale is a single player game, there is ZERO risk of being kicked of. By using this you impact only your game, not other people.